# MS Access XMLImport from text or stream instead of file?

Tags: xml, ms-access, jet

Any easy way to do the equivalent of Application.ImportXML, but with the XML as a string or text stream instead of a file? (In Access 2003.)

I want to insert records to a table with a lot of fields with data from different places in my application, and don't want to go through the hassle of setting up a parameter or dynamically generated query, I thought it might be easy to simply generate the XML and import it, but I'd rather not have to write out a file and read it back in if I can help it.

Thanks,
Eric